Bounds on error on solving $Ax=b$ for perturbed system
I am interested in solving $x$ from $Ax=b$, where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ and $m > n$, it is rectangular and even rank-deficient. This means that we can only solve it in the least-square sense. I am interested in how the error in $A$ or $b$ is mapped to the error of the solution when we take the pseudo-inverse $\hat{x} = (A+dA)^{\dagger}(b+db)$ compared to the real least-square solution $x=A^{\dagger}b$.
In the lecture note of the MIT class: Conditioning on Matrix Inversion, it derives that there is a bound on the error on $\hat{x}$:
$$ \frac{\|dx\|}{\|x\|} \leq K(A)\left(\frac{\|dA\|}{\|A\|}+\frac{\|db\|}{\|b\|}\right)$$
But they reach this inequality with the assumption that $A$ is square and invertible. I wonder if there is a more general statement that is applicable for general $A$ that can be rectangular and even rank-deficient.

I found something that might be close, but not exact, which is from this lecture note: Linear Least Squares. On pages 16 and 17, it gives two inequalities for $\|dx\|$ when trying to solve for $x=A^{\dagger}b$ in a least square sense:
$$ \frac{\|dx\|}{\|x\|} \leq K(A)\frac{1}{\cos(\theta)}\left(\frac{\|db\|}{\|b\|}\right) $$
$$ \frac{\|dx\|}{\|x\|} \leq (K(A)^2\tan(\theta)+K(A))\left(\frac{\|dA\|}{\|A\|}\right) $$
But it seems the derivation is assuming $A$ is full-rank. It is possible to be generalized to the case where $A$ is rank-deficient?

At some level it comes down to when is a small number zero.

What do you mean by that?

Brian's answer below explains what I meant in a much better way than I could have.

Suppose that $A$ $m$ by $n$ with $m>n$, and $A$ is column rank deficient, that is the rank of $A$ is strictly less than $n$.
Let $x^{\dagger}$ be the pseudoinverse solution
$x^{\dagger}=A^{\dagger}b$.
Suppose that $b$ is perturbed to $b+\delta b$.  Then the perturbed pseudoinverse solution is
$\hat{x}=A^{\dagger}(b+\delta b)$.
Thus
$\| \hat{x} - x^{\dagger} \| \leq \| A^{\dagger} \| \| \delta b \|$.
The norm of $A^{\dagger}$ will depend on the reciprocal of the smallest singular value of $A$ included in the SVD pseudoinverse.
Numerically, it can be very hard to determine whether a singular value is effectively 0.  If an extremely small singular value is included in computing $A^{\dagger}$, then $\| A^{\dagger} \|$ could be extremely large and there would be no effective bound on the change from $\hat{x}$ to $x^{\dagger}$.
The case for changes in $A$ is somewhat more complicated. Considering the change in $A$ to $A+\delta A$, and assuming no change in $b$, we have
$x^{\dagger}=A^{\dagger}b$
$\hat{x}=(A+\delta A)^{\dagger}b$.
Thus
$\| \hat{x}-x^{\dagger} \| \leq \| (A+\delta A)^{\dagger}-A^{\dagger} \| \| b \| $.
The matrix $A+\delta A$ might not have the same rank as $A$! An extremely small change $\delta A$ can create a small singular value in $A+\delta A$, making $\| (A+\delta A)^{\dagger} \|$ huge and very different from $\| A^{\dagger} \|$.  Thus there is no useful bound on $\| x^{\dagger} - \hat{x} \| $ in the case of changes to $A$.

Thank you, Prof. Borchers! Is $||A^{\dagger}||$ the minimum non-zero singular value of $A$? How can I relate the equation $||\hat{x} - x^{\dagger}|| \leq ||A^{\dagger}|| \ ||\delta b||$ to the "generalized" condition number of $A$? For the case where there is a change in $A$, is there any possible statement we can make if we assume $A+\delta A$ has the same rank as $A$?

The singular values of $A^{\dagger}$ are the reciprocals of the nonzero singular values of $A$.  The condition number that is normally used is $\sigma_{1}/\sigma_{n}$, but that's infinity for your rank deficient matrices.  In order to say anything, you'd need continuity of the singular values, and I don't think that's possible.
